# Ad serving is limited, ¿still no way to communicate with a real person?

Tags: java, android, admob

I have many questions I hope you can help me

I have 3 applications in the Play Store with banner and interstitial ads, Yesterday I received these warnings when opening my account:
[image]
[image]

First I want to clarify that my 3 apps do not violate the Play Store policies, all the work is my own and basically they are productivity tools, I have never clicked on my ads or asked anyone to do so and I always use the test ads provided by google. When the loading of the interstitial ads is completed, an AlertDialog (1.5 sec) is shown informing that an ad will be displayed so I find it difficult to accidentally click, the banners appear in a similar way.

These are the% CTR for the first 3 weeks of March (6 of 15 ad unit):

Week 1
[image]
Week 2
[image]
Week 3
[image]

I am concerned because I have read from many people who have been blocked for more than 4 months and I don't know how likely a blockage of more than 1 month is

I am very discouraged because I have invested a lot of time and although I earn very little I would really like to continue but I do not know if it is worth continuing to update something that may not be able to generate income, I think that if I have not done anything wrong I should not worry but with google bots you never know, my questions are the following:
From what percentage of CTR is considered high?
Is there any way to communicate with someone from google and show that I have not given the clicks or what can I do?
And most importantly, if someone has been in a similar situation, did you solve it? How?

Comment: This looks to be a customer service question not a programming question, which would be off-topic here.  Please see: [Are questions on prices or support of developer services on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274576) and [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a customer service question, not a programming / algorithm question.